# lucene - returning all docs that mach one field and sort by relevance of another

Tags: search, lucene

i need to be able to search for all the members of a certain group (identified by a common `groupId` field) and get them back by relevance to another field (`description`)

meaning, let's say i have the following docs indexed:

```
name="a" groupId="445" description="lives in a blue house"
name="b" groupId="445" description="has a green car"
name="c" groupId="445" description="likes blue flowers"
name="d" groupId="445" description="his eyes are brown"
name="e" groupId="445" description="her table is light-blue"
```

and i want to get them all by id (`groupId:445 AND ...`) and then sort by relevance to the word "blue"
meaning - i'd like to get a, b, c first **but** still get the others (who don't have  the word "blue" in the description at all), just with a lower score

how can i achieve that?

thanks!

Comment: A simple hackish approach would be to use a boolean query to combine your multiple queries. A better way is to use a subclass of CustomScoreQuery with getCustomScoreProvider overridden to return your subclass of CustomScoreProvider.

Comment: i've looked at CustomScoreQuery  and changing the score mechanism is a little to advanced for me at this point so i might start off with rearranging the query like you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found an answer:
programmatic construction of queries (more info here: http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html)

when i add a TermQuery to a BooleanQuery i found that i can define it as "MUST occur" or "SHOULD occur" (i think that in the query syntax it translates into '+', or lack of it, before the term)

more about Occur:
http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanClause.Occur.html

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a boost. `groupId:445^10 description:blue` for example.